# Select statement with in keyword not working as expected

Tags: oracle

i have strange problem.
I have a column in a table A in which i am storing a value in the string format joe,rose,chandler.
joe, rose and chandler correspond to 1,2 n 3 in Table B.

```
SELECT number
FROM B
WHERE name IN
 (SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT('''',name),'''') AS name
 FROM
  (SELECT REPLACE(info_value, ',' ,''',''') AS name
 FROM B
 )
);
```

The below sql results in 'joe','rose','chandler'

```
      (SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT('''',name),'''') AS name
       FROM
      (SELECT REPLACE(info_value, ',' ,''',''') AS name
       FROM B
      )
    );
```

**But it is not retrieving anything.**

But if i pass the result set directly to same sql as shown below, then it is working fine.

```
    SELECT number
     FROM B
    WHERE name IN('joe','rose','chandler')
```

Please let me know if some one has any pointers on this.

Comment: why all the CONCATs?

Comment: If i don't put the concat, then result set of subselect is   joe','rose','chandler which is still not yielding any results.The concat is putting a single quote at the end as well as begining.

Comment: but why do you want all that comma and quote stuff on that result set?  dont you just want to match the data? - and also is the info_value really from the same table B as the number?

Comment: oh - i think i see what you are asking... you have a string with the names all in one column separated by commas?  this is a huge normalization problem.  You will not be able to pass that in as  string the way you are attempting.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that i  have a string with all the names in one column separated by commas. Thanks Randy

Comment: @MT0...yes it won't work as it will treat all the names as a single string

Comment: best thing to do would be fix the normalization sooner than later and avoid this in the future.

Comment: @Randy..i resolved it using java code...thanks...sure..the normalization is in plan

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/410c5/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

If you create a function to split the list into a collection:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION splitList(
  str   VARCHAR2,
  delim VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST DETERMINISTIC
AS
  o_list SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
  p_prev NUMBER(4,0) := 1;
  p_next NUMBER(4,0);
BEGIN
  o_list := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST();
  IF ( str IS NULL ) THEN
    NULL;
  ELSIF ( delim IS NULL ) THEN
    o_list.EXTEND( 1 );
    o_list(1) := str;
  ELSE
    p_next := INSTR( str, delim, p_prev, 1 );
    WHILE ( p_next > 0 ) LOOP
      IF ( p_next > p_prev ) THEN
        o_list.EXTEND( 1 );
        o_list( o_list.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( str, p_prev, p_next - p_prev );
      END IF;
      p_prev := p_next + LENGTH( delim );
      p_next := INSTR( str, delim, p_prev, 1 );
    END LOOP;
    IF ( p_prev <= LENGTH( str ) ) THEN
      o_list.EXTEND( 1 );
      o_list( o_list.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( str, p_prev );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN o_list;
END splitList;
/
```

Then you can do:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA ( info_value ) AS
SELECT 'joe,rose,chandler' FROM DUAL
/

CREATE TABLE TableB ( "number", name ) AS
          SELECT 1, 'joe' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'rose' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'alice' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'chandler' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'bob' FROM DUAL
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT "number"
FROM   TableB
WHERE  name IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
                 FROM   TABLE(
                          splitList(
                            ( SELECT info_value
                              FROM TableA
                            )
                          )
                        )
               )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/410c5/1/0)**:

```
| number |
|--------|
|      1 |
|      2 |
|      4 |
```